# Using nested functions in XSLT (function inside function)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, xslt

I have the following two functions in XSLT 1.0

- ShortenDetail
- RemoveHTML

I am trying to first clean "Detail" column using RemoveHTML function and then I want to shorten it using ShortenDetail function.

This is how I am doing it but it is not working and giving error.

```
<xsl:call-template name="ShortenDetail">
     <xsl:call-template name="RemoveHtml">
           <xsl:with-param name="String" select="@Detail"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:call-template>
```

How do I use nested functions in XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how  `ShortenDetail` template is implemented.

For templates:

```
    <!-- Fake ShortenDetail -->  
    <xsl:template name="ShortenDetail">
         <xsl:param name="String" />
         <xsl:value-of select="$String"/>
    </xsl:template>

   <!-- Fake RemoveHtml -->
   <xsl:template name="RemoveHtml">
     <xsl:param name="String" />
     <xsl:value-of select="$String"/>
   </xsl:template>
```

this is the correct way to chain/pipe templates:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ShortenDetail">
        <xsl:with-param name="String">
             <xsl:call-template name="RemoveHtml">
                       <xsl:with-param name="String" select="@Detail"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Ok I will have a look at it in the morning tomorrow.